# InstallShield LE error: This installation package is not supported by this processor type

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, installshield-le

1. I am trying to build a setup.exe file for the VSTO Outlook addIn
   using InstallShield LE.
2. When I Build the SetupInstaller, it gives me a setup.exe in the output folder and this setup works on 64 bit Windows OS.
3. But when I install the same exe in 32 Bit OS it gives me an error "This installation package is not supported by this processor type" after extracting the msi files.

I have tried:

1. Changing the Platform in Configuration Manager from "ANY CPU" to
   x86, but  still keep getting the same error.
2. Installing dependencies mention in .csproj > ProjectTypeGuids
3. Changing Summary Template in .isl > template to Intel

I have also went through other stackoverflow similar question, but did not find a solution in my case yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If InstallShield Limited Edition is creating a 64-bit package (which matches the symptoms you describe), this is because it believes you are installing resources to a 64-bit location. This could be a file under ProgramFiles64Folder or System64Folder, or a registry key under the 64-bit area. If you can find such, remove them and build again, and the result should be a 32-bit package.

It's also possible that some 64-bit registry keys come from performing COM extraction on your program, but that is unlikely to be the sole cause, as you tried ensuring your program is 32-bit.

If you have other MSI tools, you can search your built MSI for any 64-bit [components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007) (Attributes value includes the 256 bit), and try to track back their source. However InstallShield LE doesn't display components, so this may not be as easy to find and edit them if the component's name isn't obvious.